# Inserting Macros in argument of \sindex[]{} aren't expanded

Tags: macros, indexing, expansion

I've to build an individual register with `\sindex[]{}` from the splitxdx package from an outside generated TeX code. The call name of people with two firstnames is sometimes put in braces, sometimes not. So for the index the braces should be removed.

I wrote a short macro `rmBrcs` which removes the braces very well - but the macro expansion in sindex dosen't work here and therefore I get three lines in the index file:

```
\indexentry[myindex]{Test!\rmBrcs{\testone}}{1}
\indexentry[myindex]{Test!\rmBrcs{\testtwo}}{2}
\indexentry[myindex]{Test!\testthree|textbf}{3}
```

with the result:

[image]

I've seen the [Inserting commands in argument of \sindex[]{} aren't expanded: @-symbol showing up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202591/inserting-commands-in-argument-of-sindex-arent-expanded-symbol-showing) discussion, but the answer dosen't help here, cause unfortunately I get an mixture of expanded/unexpanded index entries.

Here's my MWE that produced the output above:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{xstring}

% Remove Braces
\def\rmBrcsTmp{rmBrcsTmp}%
\def\rmBrcs#1{\IfSubStr{#1}{(}{\StrDel{#1}{(}[\rmBrcsTmp]\StrDel{\rmBrcsTmp}{)}\/}{#1}}%

\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\makeindex 
\newindex{myindex}

\def\testone{(John) Bob Doe}
\def\testtwo{John Bob Doe}
\def\testthree{John Bob Doe}

\begin{document} 

Test on page 1:
\sindex[myindex]{Test!\rmBrcs{\testone}}

\newpage
Test on page 2:
\sindex[myindex]{Test!\rmBrcs{\testtwo}}

\newpage
Test on page 3:
\sindex[myindex]{Test!\testthree}

\newpage
\printindex[myindex]

\end{document}
```

Another idea is to remove the braces upfront before it get's into `sindex`, but this is beyond my TeX/LaTeX knowlegde.

Comment: `\sindex` expands *no* macro. If you wrap up as argument to a command, expansion happens when writing on the `idx` file, but your `\rmBrcr` macro doesn't work purely by expansion, so you have to use a different approach.

Comment: @egreg: That's what I'm afraid too. This means, one way is to remove the braces before I feed \sindex. All my efforts failed in this direction. At the end I wasn't able to put 'John Doe' as **value** in an (new) definiton.

Comment: @LuisPotter You just have to use expansion, rather than `\StrDel` as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

`\sindex`, like `\index` expands *no* macro by design, unless it's called as argument to another command.

However, your `\rmBrcs` command doesn't work purely by expansion, in particular `\StrDel` is not performed during a `\write` operation, so you don't get what you want anyway with the trick

```
\newcommand{\Sindex}[2][]{\sindex[#1]{#2}}
```

or similar.

You have to take another approach and remove the parentheses using only macro expansion, besides using the trick above.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}

\newindex{potter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmBrcs}[1]{\expandafter\@rmBrcs#1()\@nil}
\def\@rmBrcs#1(#2)#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1}%
  {\@rmBrcs#1#2#3\@nil}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\Sindex}[2][]{\sindex[#1]{#2}}% for expanding contents during \write

\def\testone{(John) Bob Doe}
\def\testtwo{John Bob Doe}
\def\testthree{John Bob Doe}

\begin{document} 

\rmBrcs{\testone}$|$\rmBrcs{\testtwo}$|$\rmBrcs{\testthree}

Test on page 1:
\Sindex[potter]{Test!\rmBrcs{\testone}}

\newpage
Test on page 2:
\Sindex[potter]{Test!\rmBrcs{\testtwo}}

\newpage
Test on page 3:
\Sindex[potter]{Test!\testthree}

\newpage
\printindex[potter]

\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the produced `potter.idx` file:

```
\indexentry[potter]{Test!John Bob Doe}{1}
\indexentry[potter]{Test!John Bob Doe}{2}
\indexentry[potter]{Test!John Bob Doe}{3}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `\rmbrcs` as expand-only macro:

```
\def\rmbrcs#1{\expandafter\rmbrcsA#1()\end}
\def\rmbrcsA#1(#2)#3\end{\ifx\end#3\end #1\else \rmbrcsA#1#2#3\end\fi}
```

There is no need to worry about tail recursion (dangling `\fi`) as the argument here will be simple text not some recursive thing.

Comment: @wipet the index macro reads its argument verbatim so the macros won't expand at all unless you defeat that (as egreg commented in his answer)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assumed that expansion of `\sindex` parameter is solved and that it is not main point of the question, because OP knows about this and he show the right link in his question. He asked only for expand only `\rmbrcs`.

Comment: I've tided up the comments here and added the key (objective) point to the answer. Please try to keep comments to technical issues/improvements.

Comment: @JosephWright OK, where is the archive of this interesting discussion?